# Accessing a property of a state variable in react and using it for comparison

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am brand new to react. In my application I have two state variables, "dishes" (an object containing details of various dishes such as "id", "name" etc) and "selectedDish" (a numerical value). When the user clicks on a dish in the menu (rendered by the "Menu" component), the selectedDish variable is updated to the id of the dish selected (I have checked that this is working).
Now I want to get the dish selected by doing
`dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish)=>{return dish.id===this.state.selectedDish})[0]}`
and then pass it as a prop to another component ( DishDetail).

My problem is that I just cannot seem to select a dish using the above method. (I get the error "this.props.dish" is undefined from the DishDetail component). Am I doing something wrong?

```html
class Main extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    dishes: DISHES,
    selectedDish: null
  };
}


onDishSelect(dishId){
    this.setState({selectedDish : dishId})
}


  render(){

    
  

    return (
      <div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes}   onClick={(dishId)=>{
                    this.onDishSelect(dishId)}}/>
                <DishDetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish)=>
                    { 
                        return dish.id===this.state.selectedDish
                    })[0]} />
            </div>
          </div>
      
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

DishDetail Component

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardBody, CardText, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';


class DishDetail extends Component {

    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state ={
        }
    }



    render(){


        return (
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m1">
                    <Card>
                        <CardImg width="100%" src = {this.props.dish.image} alt = {this.props.dish.name}/>

                        <CardBody>
                                <CardTitle>{this.props.dish.name}</CardTitle>
                                <CardText>{this.props.dish.description}</CardText>
                        </CardBody>

                    </Card>
                     
                </div>

        )


    }


}

export default DishDetail;
```

Comment: Well, you have to show as DishDetail component's code don't you.

Comment: You can use DishDetail component in Menu Component for each dishes. If you do this you need not worry about all these.

Comment: Added it in. Thanks!

Comment: are you sure this doesn't work. It runs perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are getting is because of the initial state being null

i.e `selectedDish: null`

Add a check in your DishDetails component to not render until dish prop is not null.

```
render(){
        const { dish } = this.props;
        
        if (!dish) {
           return null;
        }
        
        return (
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m1">
                <Card>
                    <CardImg width="100%" src = {this.props.dish.image} alt = {this.props.dish.name}/>

                    <CardBody>
                            <CardTitle>{this.props.dish.name}</CardTitle>
                            <CardText>{this.props.dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>

                </Card>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: this is what I was thinking but can you shed some light on why this seems to work even when dish is not defined. React should just not render anything

Comment: When you are rendering a variable which is undefined it does not render anything but when you try to access property from an undefined variable it does not find its key from the undefined variable and throws an error.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! I had been pulling my hair out over this and almost stayed up one whole night trying to figure it out.